# How to assign dynamic element id in jQuery when onMouseOver in a href tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 3 hyperlinks and DIV randomly generated by PHP script with dynamic ids. For example,

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=xy1" id="xy1" onMouseover="analyze('final', 'xy1')">xy1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=ay2" id="ay2" onMouseover="analyze('final', 'ay2')">ay2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=am3" id="am3" onMouseover="analyze('final', 'am3')">am3</a>

<div id="xy1"></div>
<div id="ay2"></div>
<div id="am3"></div>
```

I want to display some text based on the `onMouseover` event through a function `analyze()` in jQuery. For example,

```
function analyze(db, target) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "toThumb.php",
    data: 'db=' + db + '&id=' + target,
    success: function(output){ $("#"+target).html(output); }
  });
}
```

Here, the element id `#xy1` must be automatically assigned based on `onMouseover` event. Like **xy1** as a value of a variable name. Maybe on the next `onMouseover` event it will be **ay2** or **am3**.

I tried to set with `$("#"+target).html(output);` It failed... If I test individually with `$("#xy1").html(output);` OR `$("#ay2").html(output);` OR `$("#am3").html(output);` It works fine.

Does my way of coding is wrong? Or, Can I use `this` instead of passing parameters?

Comment: don't use same id twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Rahul Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6578921/rahul-patel). I did three changes in my coding.

(1) Removed `id`

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=xy1" onMouseover="analyze('final', 'xy1')">xy1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=ay2" onMouseover="analyze('final', 'ay2')">ay2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=am3" onMouseover="analyze('final', 'am3')">am3</a>
```

(2) Changed `id` to `class`

```
<div class="xy1"></div>
<div class="ay2"></div>
<div class="am3"></div>
```

(3) Changed `$("#"+target).html(output);` to `$("."+target).html(output);`

Now problem solved...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

In your html you have to pass your id in data-target attribute like this.

**Example:-**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=xy1" data-target="xy1" onMouseover="analyze(this)">xy1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=ay2" data-target="ay2" onMouseover="analyze(this)">ay2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=am3" data-target="am3" onMouseover="analyze(this)">am3</a>

<div id="xy1"></div>
<div id="ay2"></div>
<div id="am3"></div>
```

Then in your jquery you can get data value. and pass your data based on this data value.

```
function analyze(this)
{
    var getTargetId = $(this).data("target");
    $("#"+getTargetId).html(data); 
}
```

Comment: The line `$("#"+getTargetId).html(data);` does not changes to (for example) `$("#xy1").html(data);`. It remains same.

Answer (score 1):

First of all id should be unique in DOM. And in place of it you can use class as below.

Please check below working demo.

```js
function analyze(ele){
  $("."+ele.id).html(ele.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=xy1" id="xy1" onMouseover="analyze(this)">xy1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=ay2" id="ay2" onMouseover="analyze(this)">ay2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=am3" id="am3" onMouseover="analyze(this)">am3</a>

<div class="xy1"></div>
<div class="ay2"></div>
<div class="am3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is interesting and somewhat working. But, does not exactly work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to duplicate IDs within the document. According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id):

> `id = ID`
>
> A unique identifier for the element.
>   There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.

Also, there is no sense in displaying the items in different containers, as you might simply generate them with PHP as well.

```js
function analyze(node) {
  $('#container').html(node.innerHTML /* whatever */);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">(empty)</div>

<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=xy1" id="xy1" onmouseover="analyze(this)">xy1</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=ay2" id="ay2" onmouseover="analyze(this)">ay2</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/find.php?id=am3" id="am3" onmouseover="analyze(this)">am3</a>
```

Comment: My aim is not to capture ID. I am trying to display text in particular DIV only.

Comment: @ak-SE, hmm, I haven't mentioned capturing an ID. In fact, you don't need to capture IDs. Well, my answer contains a sample code of "displaying text in particular DIV". You can easily replace the node ID with another value.

Comment: Sorry for my words. I did not mean like that. Actually I want to assign a dynamic id, like `$("#xy1").html(output....);`. Here, the id `xy1` must change automatically. The output will be displayed based on the Ajax. I have just before elaborated my question.